# DefaultHTTPClient throwing unknown exception

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I'm try to retrieve the response of a POST to a URL in an Android Java Environment:

Here's my code:

```
          try{
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/post.php");
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
             
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("data1", "OK");
                    jsonObject.put("data2", "OK2");
             
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonString", jsonObject.toString()));
                    postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);
                    
                    System.out.println(response);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("DIED");
            }
```

Sure enough, it returns "DIED".
If I change `System.out.println("DIED");` to: `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`
then my application crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `System.out.println(e)` instead. Or `e.printStackTrace()`. Or at the very least `System.out.println(e.getClass())`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Are you sure this lines will show when running Android code?

Comment: Maybe exception was created withoud message. Try `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Android does not show the standard console output. Use `Log.e("TAG", e)` (you will need to import `android.util.Log`) and then see the error in the LogCat.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: I was assuming the OP already had that covered given that his current code *apparently* reports "DIED".

Comment: So, I found why it was throwing this exception. All internet connections now need to be done in an AsyncTask class. For anyone wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android.util.Log` class for Logger..

```
catch(Exception e)
  {
     Log.e("Exception:",e.toString());
      // or  
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: @Boris Strandjev  - Then? He wants to check Exception, How can I help him on this question?

Comment: You are right. Maybe I misread `What am I doing wrong?` like help me solve the error and not as `help me print the error`.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - In SO there are so many user and new users which are don't know "how to ask question" - but here we can do as possible help by trying understand their questions.

Comment: Maybe I was confused by your handle. Usually such users are totally unexperienced and do not act quite adequately. Obviously neither your case nor @JonSkeet's is like that. Sorry once more.

Comment: Sorry, my question is a little ambiguous. I primarily want to know *why* I am getting the exception in the first place.